# Pass Parameter from aspx to xaml

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-5.0

Hi I am new in Silverlight. Below is my aspx code

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/ICartPrinting.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="initparams" id="initParams" runat="server" value="key1=10" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

I am passing value `10` using `initparams` tag.  My `MainPage.xaml` code is

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var paramvalues = e.InitParams;
        foreach (var item in paramvalues)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Value);    
        }
    }
```

As per this code message box should be show but when i run application, no message box is appear. I am also unable to debug silverlight code. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call visual controls during application startup.  Try something like this to get the value:

```
<param name="initParams" value="key1=10" />

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.InitParams)
    {
        this.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}


public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    string module = string.Empty;
    int key1 = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (App.Current.Resources.Contains("key1"))
        {
            int.TryParse(App.Current.Resources["key1"].ToString(), out key1);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the RootVisual before you can display a MessageBox.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();

    var paramvalues = e.InitParams;
    foreach (var item in paramvalues)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.Value);    
    }
}
```